# Javascript in .ascx file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have `.ascx` controls which I load on the page using renderpartial. I have need where in I want to hide some Div tag on the page where I am loading the control. 
I added a Javascript to the `.ascx` file, but it seems that it does not get included in the page and hence I cannot hide the DIV tag when I load the control.

Any help??

Comment: Did you examine the page source for the user control code?

Answer (score 0):

You should view source of your control and also if you are using update panel on the page and loading the script at runtime then it may be the root cause as well.